# localhost server can not connect wamp even apache is working

Tags: iis-7, localhost, wamp

I am using wammp server and apache is working(color is green). Yesterday it was workng but today its not working. Today when I tried to open localhost IIS7 is opened first then I closed (Turn windows features on/off) IIS . And now when I tried to connect localhost it can not connect to server. What might be the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys sorry for the question I changed my port and forget to write it near localhost problem is solved :)